# How to use swift to transfer data between two viewController , do not use storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, transfer

I have two viewController : first and second.
Now, first viewcontroller have a tableView, when I click a cell, jump to the second viewController
and I want to send a image name from first to second, then second controller presentation the image 
how to do this?

The language is swift. 
tips: do not use storyboard,just code!!

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll let you know there are a ton of examples of this.

In whatever method you are telling the second view controller to present:

`let secondViewController: SecondViewController = SecondViewController()
secondViewController.imageFromFirstViewController = self.imageToPass
self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)`

The syntax may not be perfect because I haven't done much Swift development but you should get the idea.

Comment: thank you, my question is how to issue a variable let other viewController know, then i can do like this: `second.image = self.imageToPass`

Comment: Yeah just create a non-private `var` in the second view controller. Then the first view controller can access it.

Comment: er. i mean you idea, i issue a var before `class secondViewController:UIViewController { }` but, the first cant use second.var from second to use. it's mean first cant see the var

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your second view, lets say:

```
@property UIImage *myImage
```

Now, in your first view, you have the image from your cell that was tapped - so all thats left is to tell the second view what it is.

```
let myNewView: ViewClassGoesHere = ViewClassGoesHere()
myNewView.myImage = imageFromFirstView
```

As you can see, it's pretty much the same as in Objective-C, only the way you instantiate the second view is slightly different.

Comment: my xcode version is 6.1, int the seconde viewController i cant use "@property" to issue , i don't know why . in my project, only use swift